# "skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc" issue while make tls package in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, ssl, gnutls

I am facing below issue while doing `make tls1.6`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
: libtls1.6.so
(echo 'package ifneeded tls 1.6 \
        "[list source [file join $dir tls.tcl]] ; \
         [list tls::initlib $dir libtls1.6.so]"'\
    ) > pkgIndex.tcl
```

What could be the possible resolutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over the following steps.

1. Check against what architecture you are compiling `tls` with `make`
2. Reconfigure the `tls` package with the same architecture as you have for `libc.so` lib.

You can determine target architecture of binary file `libc.so` with `file` linux command like this :

`file /usr/lib/libc.so`

Comment: @demius 
[root@server tls1.6]# file /usr/lib/libc.so
/usr/lib/libc.so: ASCII C program text
[root@server tls1.6]#
that seems to be a ASCII program file .

Comment: @erpm31 no way libc.so is a text file ! Check the architecture of the executable (x86 or x64)